# Adding Gson as local dependency fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gson

I'll be using Gson Extra libraries (that are not included in Maven?, and will therefore have to download Gson files from https://github.com/google/gson and add the library as a local dependency in Android Studio 3.1 with gradle:3.1.0.

What I have done:

1. Created new Android Studio project with the name TestGsonExtras
2. Downloaded Gson zip file from https://github.com/google/gson
3. Unzipped the Gson zip in the folder TestGsonExtras\subProject\gson
   [with directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ6FK.png)
4. Updated settings.gradle to contain 
   `include ':app', ':subProject:gson'` 

   (No error when doing this, 
   [gson project visible in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPgSN.png) )
5. Updated build.gradle for the module to contain local gson reference :
   `implementation project(':subProject:gson')`

Step #5 results in these errors:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :subProject:gson.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :subProject:gson.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :subProject:gson.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :subProject:gson.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :subProject:gson.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'll be using Gson Extra libraries (that are not included in Maven?

The extra **package is not published** in Maven.
You can check this [issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1123).

> include ':app', ':subProject:gson'

It can't work in this way.

Gradle is waiting for a `build.gradle` (a module file, not a top level file) in this folder `subProject/gson` but this file doesn't exist.

The best way to use the classes is just to include source-code of extra folders in your project.

Comment: Hi @fredimx40 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.